# FacebookSDK in React Native fails

Tags: facebook, react-native

I get the following errormessage after setting up Facebook integration after the official guides provided by facebook themself:

```
com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk does not exists
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage ;
```

I checked that directory and both the folder and the file exists.
I downloaded and linked the sdk without any issues reported. I added the appID string to **values/strings.xml** and the required meta-tag in the **AndroidManifest.xml**

I did not add anything to the build.gradle file since the guide said to not bother with it.

So what may be causing this? And how do I resolve it?

Comment: Have you solved it yet?